# How to recreate this type of sine jamming?

Tags: digital-communications, digital-modulation, bpsk

I'm trying to recreate this type of sine/tonal jamming in Python as part of my graduation project.

I found this dataset in a published paper that described this type of jamming as "Sine Jamming" with no further explanation. I tried several methods for adding tonal jamming but the constellation diagram doesn't look like that. Digital communication is just a part of my project and it's not my strongest subject.

How is the pure BPSK signal (with AWGN) turn into the sine-jammed signal?

Non-jammed BPSK (with AWGN) constellation diagram:

[image: Non-Jammed BPSK (with AWGN) Constellation Diagram]

Sine-jammed BPSK constellation diagram:

[image: Sine-Jammed BPSK Constellation Diagram]